# How to fix System.AggregateException in ASP.NET Core Web API taking IFormFile?

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, iformfile

I am creating an ASP.NET Core Web API which will get image and store it in the a backend folder and send the path to db. But it's giving the following error repeatedly:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

Below is the API action method:

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[Route("GetAll")]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
        try
        {
            var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            var folderName = Path.Combine("Auxiliary","Images");
            var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);

            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                var fileName=ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, fileName);
                var dbPath = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }

                return Ok(new {dbPath});
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Internal Server Error: {ex}");
        }
}
```

And in `startup.cs` file, I have added below code in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(o =>
        {
            o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            o.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
        });
```

And in thew `Configure` method:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Auxiliary")),
            RequestPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Auxiliary")
        });
```

Comment: If you are able to reproduce the issue on your development machine, could you try to debug it and see on which line the error occurs? Is it coming from an API or from your DB? Please check whether the file path gets stored in the dB? further, check whether you are able to perform any other operation with your DB?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I have tried just to get the image, where the postman gives the error. Even I'm not able to debug the API as it shows the error just on calling the API from POSTMAN. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

Comment: It looks like there is some issue with the SSL connection, are you able to test the same with the HTTP protocol? Does it work?

Comment: @Deepak-MFST there was some middleware that was blocking, i got it

Comment: Thanks for informing us that you found the cause of the issue. If possible, you could post your solution as an answer and accept it when it is available to accept after 48 hrs. It could help other community members in the future with similar issues. Thanks for your understanding